# Create a New ASP.NET_SessionId when Session Times Out

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies, session-state

I want to create a brand new ASP.NET_SessionId when the Session Times out on my website. I think the event that fires when your session times out is Session_End in Global.asax file. So I would like to do something in this event

Comment: Actually, can you provide some info on why you want a brand new session id?  It might help us guide you to an answer.

Comment: We are saving SessionID in the table, and everytime user logs in we want him to have a new Session

Answer (score 1):

To delete current session, it will fire on `Session.Abandon()`:

**Global.asax**

```
public void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sessionId = this.Session.SessionID;

    // Query to delete User's current session
    //...
    //...
}
```

So you would redirect the user to the login form to generate a new Session.